how to use sql innerjoin of two columns criteria from one table in an MS access database
I'M Trying to use sql innerjoin of two columns criteria from one table in an MS access database And I only want one sql query.
Please Guide Me
Thanks
SELECT PERSON.IDPERSON, MASTERPERSON.PERSONNAME, PERSON.[DATE], MASTERPERSON.LOCATION, FORMAT(PERSON.DATE,'dddd') AS DAYS
FROM PERSON INNER JOIN MASTERPERSON ON PERSON.IDPERSON = MASTERPERSON.IDPERSON;

Result from Sql Above :



IDPERSON
PERSONNAME
DATE
LOCATION
DAYS




1000
Rey
29-May-24
A
Wednesday


1000
Rey
30-May-24
A
Thursday


1001
Michael
29-May-24
B
Wednesday


1001
Michael
30-May-24
B
Thursday



Table PERSON



IDPERSON
DATE




1000
29-May-24


1000
30-May-24


1001
29-May-24


1001
30-May-24



Table  MASTERPERSON



IDPERSON
PERSONNAME
LOCATION




1000
Rey
A


1001
Michael
B



Table  PERSONDAYS



LOCATION
DAYS
STATUS




A
Wednesday
A10


A
Thursday
A27


B
Wednesday
B18


B
Thursday
B29



Desired Result



IDPERSON
PERSONNAME
DATE
LOCATION
DAYS
STATUS




1000
Rey
29-May-24
A
Wednesday
A10


1000
Rey
30-May-24
A
Thursday
A27


1001
Michael
29-May-24
B
Wednesday
B18


1001
Michael
30-May-24
B
Thursday
B29




Sounds like you just need another join JOIN PERSONDAYS AS pd ON pd.LOCATION = MASTERPERSON.LOCATION AND pd.DAYS = FORMAT(PERSON.DATE, 'dddd')

Does sound like need another JOIN to include PersonDays table. This would involve a compound JOIN on Location and Date/Days fields. Access is picky about use of parens with multiple JOIN clauses. Use query designer to get correct syntax.
In your case, must calculate day name from date value to JOIN on day names. Unfortunately, cannot JOIN directly to calculated value in design view. Can switch to SQL View to add this additional JOIN AND PersonDays.DAYS = FORMAT(PERSON.DATE, 'dddd') but then can never open in design view.
SELECT Person.IDPerson, MasterPerson.PersonName, Person.Date, MasterPerson.Location, PersonDays.Days, PersonDays.Status
FROM PersonDays INNER JOIN (Person INNER JOIN MasterPerson 
ON Person.IDPerson = MasterPerson.IDPerson) 
ON PersonDays.Location = MasterPerson.Location AND PersonDays.DAYS = FORMAT(PERSON.DATE, 'dddd');

Otherwise, build a query object that calculates a field with Format([Date],'dddd') then use that query in another query so design view will be able to display join.
An alternative is to use WHERE clause for this additional relationship criteria. Produces same result and can be displayed in Design View but may perform less efficiently.
SELECT Person.IDPerson, MasterPerson.PersonName, Person.Date, MasterPerson.Location, PersonDays.Days, PersonDays.Status
FROM PersonDays INNER JOIN (Person INNER JOIN MasterPerson 
ON Person.IDPerson = MasterPerson.IDPerson) 
ON PersonDays.Location = MasterPerson.Location
WHERE PersonDays.DAYS = FORMAT(PERSON.DATE, 'dddd');


Thank you for your perfect answer, Sorry I replied late

Create table #PERSON
(IDPERSON INT ,DATE Date)
insert into #PERSON values
(1000,  '29-May-24'),
(1000,  '30-May-24'),
(1001,  '29-May-24'),
(1001,  '30-May-24')


create table #MASTERPERSON
(
IDPERSON int,   PERSONNAME varchar(25), LOCATION varchar(5))
insert into #MASTERPERSON
values (
1000,   'Rey',  'A'),
(1001,  'Michael',  'B')


create table #PERSONDAYS(

LOCATION varchar(5) ,DAYS varchar(50),  STATUS varchar(20) )

insert into #PERSONDAYS values
('A',   'Wednesday',    'A10'),
('A',   'Thursday', 'A27'),
('B',   'Wednesday',    'B18'),
('B',   'Thursday', 'B29')





select * from #PERSON 
select * from #MASTERPERSON
select * from #PERSONDAYS

select p.IDPerson, m.PersonName, p.Date, m.Location, pd.Days, pd.Status
from #PERSON  as p inner join #MASTERPERSON as m
on p.IDPERSON = m.IDPERSON
inner join #PERSONDAYS  as pd on m.LOCATION = pd.LOCATION AND pd.DAYS = FORMAT(p.DATE, 'dddd')


Hi @LokeshK! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Forgive me if I am wrong, but your answer appears to be SQL code, not MS Access. I don't believe MS Access supports temporary tables. Also, it is helpful to provide explanation along with a code dump. Here's a set of guidelines for providing a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  Remember, you can edit your answer and provide details.
