How to pass variable criteria for a query used in another query?
A lot of work went into this question, so please let me know if I need to add something.
I want to combine tables in a way I have not found so far. I will do the query in ADODB in Excel. So I want to use just one query using variable criteria.
Simplified:
Table A has settings per day like:



day
prebatch
setting




mon
D1
1


mon
D2
2


mon
D3
2


mon
D4
5


mon
D5
8


thu
D1
2


thu
D2
4


thu
D3
6


thu
D4
8



Table B will be filled in like:



date
prebatch
batch
value




27-5
D1
BBD1
20


27-5
D2
BBD3
21


28-5
D1
BBD4
30


28-5
D3
BBD8
30



I need to combine them in a way that lets me see all settings for a day combined with the filled in data, joined by prebatch.
like so:



day
prebatch
setting
batch
value




mon
D1
1
BBD1
20


mon
D2
2
BBD3
21


mon
D3
2




mon
D4
5




mon
D5
8




thu
D1
2
BBD4
30


thu
D2
4




thu
D3
6
BBD8
30


thu
D4
8





with pics real data:
settings table:
fill in table:
Result of query, but it shows all filled in, so also from wrong date:
result
Using query:
SELECT tbl_inst_lab.preBatch,
   tbl_data_lab.batch, 
   tbl_data_lab.labActPak, 
   tbl_inst_lab.planEind, 
   tbl_data_lab.labVerwEind, 
   tbl_data_lab.labWerkelEind, 
   tbl_data_lab.labWerkelEindRevIV, 
   tbl_inst_lab.sort, 
   tbl_inst_lab.dag
FROM tbl_inst_lab 
LEFT JOIN tbl_data_lab 
   ON tbl_inst_lab.preBatch = tbl_data_lab.preBatch
WHERE ( ((tbl_data_lab.batch)=IIf([datum]=#5/16/2024#,[batch],"")) 
         AND ((tbl_inst_lab.dag)="do")
      ) 
    OR (((tbl_inst_lab.dag)="do"))
ORDER BY tbl_inst_lab.sort;"

result that works, but too complicated:
result
using query:
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_inst_lab.preBatch, 
    IIf([tbl_data_lab].[datum]=#5/16/2024#,[tbl_data_lab].[batch]) AS exprBatch, 
    IIf([tbl_data_lab].[datum]=#5/16/2024#,[labActPak]) AS exprlabActPak, 
    tbl_inst_lab.planEind, 
    IIf([tbl_data_lab].[datum]=#5/16/2024#,[labVerwEind]) AS exprlabVerwEind, 
    IIf([tbl_data_lab].[datum]=#5/16/2024#,[labWerkelEind]) AS exprlabWerkelEind, 
    IIf([tbl_data_lab].[datum]=#5/16/2024#,[labWerkelEindRevIV]) AS exprlabWerkelEindRevIV, 
    tbl_inst_lab.sort, tbl_inst_lab.dag
FROM tbl_inst_lab 
LEFT JOIN tbl_data_lab 
    ON tbl_inst_lab.preBatch = tbl_data_lab.preBatch
WHERE (((tbl_inst_lab.dag)="do"))
ORDER BY tbl_inst_lab.sort;"

I have tried a query (C) that uses a table (A: settings) and another query (B: filled in) as input.
but I cannot pass the variable criteria for query B when I run query C. Can't find it, and I searched a lot.
Tried doing it within Access with filled-in criteria. It works but I will be using Excel ADODB to run the query. And I will have to use variable criteria.
Also tried UNION but the tables do not have the same amount of fields.
I have a working query using expressions for every field but that is way too complicated, see question.

you should format your queries to make them readable

i am trying to get the format right but its a pain...

So you will create and save a parameterized query definition in the Access database and then run the query using ADODB.Connection and ADODB.Command from VBA code in Excel. Is that correct?

Where will the variable inputs come from? Tables do not need to have same number of fields for UNION. Use Null or some filler value for fields tables do not have. Why do you think UNION would even be appropriate? Date field is not showing a complete date value. Calculating day name from that is not possible. Seem to need a compound join on date data and prebatch. See this question that demonstrates join on calculated day name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78548162/how-to-use-sql-innerjoin-of-two-columns-criteria-from-one-table-in-an-ms-access/78552600#78552600

After more review, I don't think you have any 'variable criteria'. What you need is to just JOIN tables to associate data. Unfortunately, tables don't have a direct, natural relationship. Will have to correct that with calculation as demonstrated in other question I referenced.

to clarify:
Users will work with Excel and fill in data in a table with the settings and already filled in data from the access database. But they need to see the settings and what has already been filled in.
In the excel i use vba to get a variable date and day (day of week for setting). vba creates a sql string for ado. no parameters.
example: today is 31-5 and a Friday. so the query will get settings from a Friday and the data from 31-5. This query will run and populate the excel table. so now users see the settings for this day and can fill in data.
tried union to see if that works

Doesn't change my previous comment. Values of "31-5" etc as Date are not useful. I still don't know why you think UNION is an option. Your desired output shows data is JOINed.

Thanks for your answers.
I do not need to calculate a date or a day. These are the variables i give in the query.
I just want to combine settings for a day (i.e: 'mon') with data from a date (i.e: '03-06-2024'). But i think my problem is to big to discribe here.
So, back to the question in the title:
How to pass variable criteria for a query used in another query?
then i can combine settings and a query of data from a day.

I think i failed explaining my problem. It is complicated so i tried simplifying, but that raised more questions.
I now just use the complicated query that works perfectly.
Is there a way i can close this question or mark it as solved?
